# onclick: Have to click twice in order for a div to hide/show

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, toggle, show

I have a problem where I have to click twice in order for my JavaScript function to run.

HTML for the button:

```
<input type="button" id="logintrigger" value="Log In" onClick="hideshow();"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function hideshow() {
    var toggle = document.getElementById('logincontainer');
    toggle.style.display = toggle.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
```

I have been searching around and haven't found anything that helped.

Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

Apply **style="display:block"** explicitly to logincontainer and then change following line :
    toggle.style.display = toggle.style.display == **"block" ? "none" : "block"**;

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer. I was wondering if you know how I can get it to also hide when I click on the page? I tried: document.onclick=function() {
var toggle = document.getElementById('logincontainer');
toggle.style.display == "none";
}

Comment: @user1512677 : So what you want is when you click outside the logincontainer, it should hide, is it?

Comment: @user1512677 : Yeah I got it... inside **logincontainer** tag, call this function **onmouseover**. I mean if you have a textbox with id logincontainer (suppose), then <input type="text" id="logincontainer" **onmouseover="---Call Funtion To Toggle Display---"**/>

Comment: Well what I'm going for is a dropdown login box but, I was trying to get the login box to hide when an area of the document is clicked outside of the login box.

Comment: @user1512677 yeah do what I told you in comment above, thats the solution

Answer (score 2):

The initial state of display property is more likely to be empty. That's why till you explicitly change it - this js function gets "".